# Variable assignment and scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope, global-variables, ecmascript-5

I just have a curiosity about the difference between using var and let when assigning variables.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000);
}

output: 4
        4
        4
        4

for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000);
}

output: 0
        1
        2
        3
```

From the above code snippets, I wonder why those two codes log different results.

Comment: Because one of the problems `let` is designed to solve is the "closure in loops" problem (see the duplicate Nina tagged). In the second example, a **new** `i` variable is created for each loop iteration; the timeout callback created in that loop iteration closes over the `i` for that iteration, and so sees each individual value (since nothing changes that value). WIth the `var` version, there's only one `i` variable, so naturally all four callbacks show that one variable's value as of when they run.

Comment: mm.. I still not quite get it..

Comment: You've read the third part of [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/157247) to the linked question?

Comment: Yes, I've read it and.. I think I'm getting it, but not 100%.